# Why is one of my FontAwesome icons larger than the other two in my inline-block list?

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-size

I am using three FontAwesome icons in an inline-block list. I started with a font size set to 24px/1 and changed it to 32px/1 for all three. For some reason, the first one in the list is the only one that resized, is offset from where the others are, and overlays the text below it. I have tried to change them back to the original size but nothing changes and I have cleared my cache and browser history several times and tried three different browsers: Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. See screen capture.
[Unbalanced icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eUvL.png)

How do I correct these to all be the same size and aligned the same as the last two are?

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="sidebar-social-navigation">
<ul class="social-icons">
<li class="element facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessible.techcomm/"><span class="facebook" aria-labelledby="Facebook"></span></a><br /><a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessible.techcomm/">Facebook</a></li>

<li class="element twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/AccessTechcomm"><span class="twitter" aria-labelledby="Twitter"></span></a><br /><a href="https://twitter.com/AccessTechcomm">Twitter</a></li>

<li class="element rss"><a href="https://accessible-techcomm.org/feed/"><span class="rss" aria-labelledby="RSS"></span></a><br /><a href="https://accessible-techcomm.org/feed/">RSS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS.

```
.sidebar-social-navigation {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social-navigation ul.social-icons {
    list-style: none outside;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.element {
    position: relative;
}

ul.social-icons li.element.facebook a::before {
    content: '\f082';
    font: normal normal normal 32px/1 FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    vertical-align: top;
/*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #2222ac;  /*----Persian blue ----*/
/*  padding-left: 0.5em; */
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

ul.social-icons li.element.twitter a::before {
    content: '\f081';
    font: normal normal normal 32px/1 FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    vertical-align: top;
/*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #2222ac;  /*----Persian blue ----*/
/*  padding-left: 0.5em; */
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

ul.social-icons li.element.rss a::before {
    content: '\f09e';
    font: normal normal normal 32px/1 FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    vertical-align: top;
/*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #2222ac;  /*----Persian blue ----*/
/*  padding-left: 0.5em; */
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The improved code fixed the overly large Facebook icon and realigned it with the others. I changed the Demo font size of 16px/1 to 28px/1 and I like this size the best. However, the list is too far to the right in the sidebar. I tried to adjust things to shift it all to the left but now the icons are centered over the text and I'd like the list to line up with the left side of the sidebar. I don't know how changing right or left spacing made the icons centered. See screen capture for how they look in Firefox and in Chrome.
[How the list appears in Firefox and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBjtk.png)

Then I checked how the list looks in the Safari browser and the icons are doubled above the text and centered with the text. Very odd. Again, I've cleared cache and history in all browsers and reloaded the browsers but I still get this odd result. See screen capture in Safari browser.

[How the list looks in the Safari browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxDVj.png)

Here is the improved CSS.

```
.sidebar-social-navigation {
    margin: 0 0 -8px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-icons {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-icons .element {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.social-icons .element a::before {
    content: "";
    font: normal normal normal 28px/1 FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    vertical-align: top;
/*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #2222ac;  /*----Persian blue ----*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0 0 12px 0;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.social-icons .facebook a::before {
    content: '\f082';
}

.social-icons .twitter a::before {
    content: '\f081';
}

.social-icons .rss a::before {
    content: '\f09e';
}
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="sidebar-social-navigation">
<ul class="social-icons">
<li class="element facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessible.techcomm/"><span class="facebook" aria-labelledby="Facebook"></span></a><br /><a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessible.techcomm/">Facebook</a></li>

<li class="element twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/AccessTechcomm"><span class="twitter" aria-labelledby="Twitter"></span></a><br /><a href="https://twitter.com/AccessTechcomm">Twitter</a></li>

<li class="element rss"><a href="https://accessible-techcomm.org/feed/"><span class="rss" aria-labelledby="RSS"></span></a><br /><a href="https://accessible-techcomm.org/feed/">RSS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE to this UPDATE--A third result while saving**

Well, as I was making a copy of the HTML to add here, I accidentally hit a key, deleted it, and had to resave the widget so I could close it. Now there is a third result. The icons have shifted to the left and are centered in the sidebar, which is fine, but the text stayed in place to the right. See screen capture for how it now looks in Firefox. It is still stacked in Safari.

[How the icons shifted to the left but text stayed right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6on4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your current code, but here is an improvement code with regards to **DRY** (don't repeat yourself), on using the the same properties for `::before` 3x when you can just use it once.

With that it might fix your issue, giving changing the size it will apply to all elements at the same time.

```css
.sidebar-social-navigation {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-icons {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-icons .element {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* UPDATED CODED */
.social-icons .element a::before {
  content: "";
  font: normal 16px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #2222ac;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.social-icons .facebook a::before {
  content: '\f082';
}

.social-icons .twitter a::before {
  content: '\f081';
}

.social-icons .rss a::before {
  content: '\f09e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sidebar-social-navigation">
  <ul class="social-icons">
    <li class="element facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessible.techcomm/"><span class="facebook" aria-labelledby="Facebook"></span></a><br /><a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessible.techcomm/">Facebook</a></li>

    <li class="element twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/AccessTechcomm"><span class="twitter" aria-labelledby="Twitter"></span></a><br /><a href="https://twitter.com/AccessTechcomm">Twitter</a></li>

    <li class="element rss"><a href="https://accessible-techcomm.org/feed/"><span class="rss" aria-labelledby="RSS"></span></a><br /><a href="https://accessible-techcomm.org/feed/">RSS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your improvement to the code is much better. But two odd things are happening--the list looks the same in Firefox and Chrome but too far to the right and in Safari, the icons get doubled up. I will add an update to my question with two screen shots.

Comment: I would need to see a live snippet to debug the issue

Comment: See the sidebar box labeled "Follow Us" (sixth box down) at https://accessible-techcomm.org/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: I voted your answer up but I don't have enough rep points yet so it is a hidden vote.